# How to make apt-get retry on hash sum mismatch?

Tags: apt

I get hash sum mismatches a LOT. This ends up breaking the automated build of my dockerfiles, so I have to keep checking to see if hash sum didn't occur.

Is there a way to tell apt-get to retry on hash sum mismatch?

Comment: Which version of Linux are you using, and which release number? Please click [edit] and advise.

Comment: Did you try APT::Acquire::Retries in /etc/apt.conf?